# Low power low cost wireless transmission

Tags: wireless

I am new to this forum and looking for some advice from experts.
I am working on a project where I need to send data say temp from a sensor to a base unit.
The sensor produces analogue data. So plan is to convert analogue data to digital and transmit wirelessly to a receiver. The data is then processed and sent to other devices like mobile wirelessly.
The question is, can the output of ADC directly transmitted to the receiver using encoder instead of MCU on the transmitter side. There will be a decoder and mcu at the receiver end. 
In addition can this set up if feasible can support multiple transmitters to a single receiver?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Certainly this has been done long before MCU's were even invented. But RF must comply to standards in your region for spectral power in the license free zones. Then you need to understand Friis and Ricean Path losses to ensure an adequate Bit error rate (BER) for the path signal budget. Review commercial solutions using Biphase or any other suitable encoding for your project and understand them completely before defining your requirements in a point form specification.

Comment: Contention access transmission can be adopted in 1way systems using different time intervals like 59,60,61 to avoid contention most of the time using a CD4060 binary counter with gates with a stable Xtal clock. But obviously if you have MCU programming skills, hardware simplification is better, low cost and small size. Learn how it done commercially, is my advice

Comment: There are literally thousands of products on the market that already do this. What is the motivation for designing yet another one from scratch?

Comment: There are simple, historic ways of doing this such as an audio tone proportional to temperature.  BUT MCU solutions are quite cheap and can be more power efficient.  Especially a $1 bidirectional digital radio can do something like transmit a reading and then get back a message from the base that says "thanks, I heard you, now please to go sleep for 60 seconds to save your battery then wake up and send me a new reading" or if no response is received wake up and try more quickly, or if no response has ever been received try only every several minutes, or whatever seems best for the application.

Comment: There are an increasing number of low power Bluetooth IoT beacons becoming available.  Some have temperature sensing as standard.  -  http://ruuvitag.com/

Comment: Idea is to have a minimal viable component that consumes low power as it has to run on batteries and serves the purpose of  capturing the digital data from ADC and transmit to a receiver for further processing. Any pointers is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you need a microprocessor at each end of the radio link; to implement without these components just makes the hardware more challenging and costly to design.

The NRF24L01+ (http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01P) is an excellent choice for a radio that might fit your bill. It can support up to 6 senders (for two, the default, it needs almost zero programming). There are many simple low cost modules available on Ebay based on this device where you get to choose whatever microprocessor and A/D combination you like. You could use these readily with Arduino for example.  I've used an LNA+PA version of this to get more than 150 M of range on an RC plane.

It would also seem likely that you could get whatever A/D solution you need already built into the microprocessor, so unless you have some ultra low noise, high resolution or High speed requirement this would seem a cost/effort advantage.
One thought is the NRF24LE1 (http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24LE1) which has the radio, A/D and microprocessor (plus digital I/O, I2C, SPI, and serial) built into a single SOC. This may well be all you would need for your application providing you don't need more than 12 bit A/D resolution at 16 kbps. It supports the multiceiver 6:1 capability the same as the NRF24L01+ series
This device is really flexible and the only downside I've had in it's use is that I can't run it direct off a LiPo cell without an LDO (VDD limit is 3.6 V).

[image]

These devices are readily available as small modules as shown above on Ebay for under $4 and even if you were looking for larger scale quantities I'm sure the Chinese manufacturers would be open to customization (why re-invent the wheel).
The only down side is that the microprocessor is an 8051 variant that you might not have used before. There are plenty of free and Open source C compiler versions for the 8051.

Comment: Thank you Jack, very useful information. I have done some searches based on your inputs. I have seen another module which is wifi enabled  "WeMos D1 R2 Wi fi ESP8266" and a similar cost range. Can we compare them wrt to the function of processing the sensor information and transmitting them to the base with minimal power consumption? Secondly, if we take the approach of making them sleep, can we wake them through a remote call/interruption on demand rather than base it on a timer? Thirdly, if the number of transmitters is more than 6,say 10 or 15, then can NRF24LE1 support the scenario?